# javascript: unexpected behavior pushing into empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

The following code:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var obj1 = {};

for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    if (obj1[j.toString()])
        obj1[j.toString()] = obj1[j.toString()].push(j)
    else
        obj1[j.toString()] = [].push(j);
}
```

produced the following output:

```
   obj1
=> { '0': 1, '1': 1, '2': 1 }
```

and I would just kindly like to know why.

(I'm aware now that the following code:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var obj1 = {};

for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    if (obj1[j.toString()])
        obj1[j.toString()] = obj1[j.toString()].push(j)
    else {
        obj1[j.toString()] = [];
        obj1[j.toString()].push(j);
    }
}
```

will give me my desired output:

```
   obj1
=> { '0': [ 0 ], '1': [ 1 ], '2': [ 2 ] }
```

)

Comment: Well, `[]` is the same as `Array.prototype`, there is no empty array, and you're not pushing to anything inside `obj`. The second code snippet is the correct way of doing it, where you actually create an empty array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because, [as per the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), the `Array.prototype.push()` method returns the **Array length**, not the array itself.

You may prefer the [`concat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like so:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var obj2 = {}

for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
  var js = j.toString()
  if (obj2[js]) {
    obj2[js] = obj2[js].concat([j])
  } else {
    obj2[js] = [j]
  }
}
console.log(obj2) // => { '0': [ 0 ], '1': [ 1 ], '2': [ 2 ] }

// shorter version
var obj3 = {}

for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
  var js = j.toString()
  obj3[js] = [].concat(obj3[js] || [], [j])
}

console.log(obj3) // => { '0': [ 0 ], '1': [ 1 ], '2': [ 2 ] }
```

Comment: Did not notice the first snippet. +1

Comment: Confirmed.
[1,2,3].push(60); // 4;
[].push(90); // 1; Thanks.